# How to transpose data in .xls with a few static columns

Tags: excel, static-members, transpose, period

I need to perform a transpose with a few static columns (Fruit, Category) which can vary. Also the Period can go up to 15 years. I have tried the Transpose feature, but this can transpose an individual ROW or COLUMN whereas I want to achieve the target below.

**Current State**

```
Fruit     Category     2012    2013
Apple     Fruit        24      26
Orange    Fruit        20      32
Tomato    Vegetable    50      40
```

**Target State**

```
Fruit  Category   Period  Quantity
  Apple  Fruit     2012    24
  Apple  Fruit     2013    26
  Orange Fruit     2012    20
  Orange Fruit     2013    32
  Tomato Vegetable 2012    50
  Tomato Vegetable 2013    40
```

I am not sure if there is a standard feature in Excel that can achieve this or if there is a trick with the transpose function itself.

Comment: There is no standard feature or trick in transpose to do this.  You can either develop complex formulas, or use a VBA solution.  For the latter, I would suggest developing a user defined object with properties of fruit, category, year and quantity; collecting these objects and then writing them out in your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a standard 'trick' (unpivot with multiple consolidation ranges). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120). Assuming `Fruit` is in Sheet1!A1, in the new sheet in B2 of an inserted B column:

```
 =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,0)
```

Then select all, Copy, Paste Special..., Values, filter to select `Category` in ColumnC, delete all visible rows other than first, unfilter and rename column labels.